# Haskell, with a tuple perform BIDMAS and print result

Tags: haskell, tuples

Hey guys i'm stuck and i'm not sure how to proceed:

With a tuple (2,4) have to perform all operations and print with the result, e.g.

(2,4,'+',6),(2,4,'*',8)

my idea was something like this

operaciones x = [(x,Ops,finalValue) | x <- x, Ops <- Ops, finalValue <- finalValue]

however i am unsure as how to assing multiplication addition etc and calculate the result of the operation... Any suggestions to lead me on track?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the first thing to do is to make a list of operations and their names

```
ops = [( (*), '*'), ( (+), '+'), ( (-), '-'), ( div, '/')] 
-- div is integer division
```

next we deal with the actual funciton:

```
operations (x, y) = [ (x, y, do something here) | (op, name) <- ops]
```

Where `do something here` formats the name and results. Since this is pretty straightforward (hint just apply the op to x and y) I won't give the full solution away. This is a good start though.

Comment: Thanks i see what you've done there! I had an initial list with all the opperands but hadn't thought of assigning them names individually!

Comment: Im glad you found my answer helpful, if it solves your problem you can check the green check beside it to mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1):

A first solution could of course be

```
operations (x, y) = [ (x, y, '+', x+y), (x, y, '*', x*y) ]
```

Just extend with more tuples for more operations.

Comment: I see, and i could also add predicates to ensure there's no redundancy such as (4,2,'-',2) and (4,2,'/',2) producing the same result or checking ineteger division with mod, thanks!

Comment: Okay so i have extended operations, however what if i wanted to add conditions to each statement before the were printed? for example addition can always evaluate but divsion only if x ´mod´ y = integer, x-y only if xis greater than y and multiplication also always true, so i only want 2 conditions for 2 operations that should not apply to all but i don't see it working -.- (can't get it to work)